# UITableViewCell setHighlighted, setSelected "animateAlongsideTransition" or similar

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to be able to add custom animations to subclasses of **UITableViewCell** that would override methods such as:

```
override func setHighlighted(highlighted: Bool, animated: Bool) {

}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {

}
```

and **match the animation curve and animation duration for the default animations those methods perform**.

In other words, how can I find the information about the current animations provided by Apple. I need this in order to add my own custom animations that perfectly matches the default ones

Answer (score 5):

You can subclass your custom cell in your table view.

And here I create a simple example in Swift where I change the value of a label inside the cell:

```
import UIKit

class userTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
@IBOutlet weak var userLabel: UILabel!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    self.highlighted = false
    self.userLabel.alpha = 0.0
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    if selected {
        self.highlighted = true
    } else {
        self.highlighted = false
    }

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

override var highlighted: Bool {
    get {
        return super.highlighted
    }
    set {
        if newValue {
            // you could put some animations here if you want
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.7, delay: 1.0, options: .CurveEaseOut, animations: {
                self.userLabel.text = "select"
                self.userLabel.alpha = 1.0

                }, completion: { finished in
                print("select")
            })
        }
        else {
            self.userLabel.text = "unselect"
        }
        super.highlighted = newValue
    }
}

}
```

And with the storyboard what you must have:
[image: screenshot of Xcode storyboard]

Comment: I meant how I can add animations inside those overrides that match the animation curve and length of the default animations of the superclass (UITableViewCell)?

Comment: I've edited the code with animation. There is a great tutorial from raywenderlich [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/113674/ios-animation-tutorial-getting-started)

Comment: Thanks Stéphane. It's not what I was looking for though:

**and match the animation curve and animation duration for the default animations those methods perform.**

I've updated my question to improve clarity

Comment: Ah yes ;). Now I understand.

Comment: Shorter: `self.highlighted = selected`